# Why are my meshes moving slowly?

Tags: mesh, objects

I am modeling a wing after this picture with individual feathers. Now that I have lots of them I notice in object mode items move slow + can hear pc fan rev up (I think it's the video card).Still new 2 Blender, probably goofed again and it's something simple, thanks in advance for the help.[image]

Comment: Hello ! There could easily be several dozens of explanations, unfortunately. Could you add a little bit more of a background and I think you forgot to add a picture ?

Comment: Maybe your mesh is too high in polygons, in that case you need to reduce the number of faces

Comment: @Gorgious, I think I got the photo there now, thanks.

Comment: It looks like your feathers have a very high number of polygons, how did you create them ?

Comment: I created them with an extruded circle, 8-10 loop cuts then assigning center three rows of vertices as a group, assigned that group in Particle Properties as hair,  # of hairs 2500 with 3 sections. I did this because I wanted a lot of detail.